# Passing data from Ajax to Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to pass data from AJAX to my Laravel Controller. But the data is not getting passed. Here are my controller and blade code. 
Data is not getting passed from blade through Ajax. My controller is not receiving data.

Controller File:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $new_name='';
    $new_email='';
    $new_clg='';
    $new_university='';
    $new_stream='';


   $user = DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email', 'College', 'stream','university')->get();
  /* print_r($request->jsonString);*/
  foreach($user as $d){
        $new_name= $d->name;
        $new_email=$d->email;
        $new_clg=$d->College;
        $new_university=$d->university;
         $new_stream=$d->stream;
  }

    $name1 = explode(",", $request->jsonString);/*
    $name2 = explode('["', $name1);
    $name3 = explode('"', $name1);*/
    $temp = explode('"',$request->jsonString);
   // $temp1  =   explode('"',$temp);
    print_r($temp);
    $Q1=$temp[1];
    $Q2=$temp[3];
    $Q3=$temp[5];
    $Q4=$temp[7];
    $Q5=$temp[9];
    $Q6=$temp[11];
    $Q7=$temp[13];
    $Q8=$temp[15];
    $Q9=$temp[17];
    $Q10=$temp[19];
    $Q11=$temp[21];
    $Q12=$temp[23];
    $Q13=$temp[25];
    $Q14=$temp[27];
    $Q15=$temp[29];
    $Q16=$temp[31];        // $this->validate(request(),[

    //  $user =
    //  //'answers.*'=> 'required|' 

    // ]);  ["0.3s"]
   // $result = 0;

   //  $test = Test::create([
   //      'user_id' => Auth::id(),
   //      'result'  => $result,
   //  ]);

     $report = master::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
             'user_name' => $new_name,
            'user_email' => $new_email,
            'Stream' => $new_stream,
            'University' => $new_university,
            'College_Institution' => $new_clg,
            'Q1' => $Q1,
            'Q2' => $Q2,
            'Q3' => $Q3,
            'Q4' => $Q4,
            'Q5' => $Q5,
            'Q6' => $Q6,
            'Q7' => $Q7,
            'Q8' => $Q8,
            'Q9' => $Q9,
            'Q10' => $Q10,
            'Q11' => $Q11,
            'Q12' => $Q12,
            'Q13' => $Q13,
            'Q14' => $Q14,
            'Q15' => $Q15,
            'Q16' => $Q16
            ]);
       $report->save();
    foreach ($request->input('questions', []) as $key => $question) {
        $status = 0;

        if ($request->input('options.'.$question) != null
            && QuestionsOption::find($request->input('options.'.$question))
        ) {

            $status = 1;
            $result++;
        }
        else {

           return redirect()->back();
        }

        // TestAnswer::create([
        //     'user_id'     => Auth::id(),
        //     'test_id'     => $test->id,
        //     'question_id' => $question,
        //     'option_id'   => $request->input('answers.'.$question),
        //     'correct'     => $status,
        // ]);
    }
   //  DB::insert('insert into master values(?)',[$report]);
    //$report->insert()

   // $test->update(['result' => $result]);

  //  return redirect()->route('results.show', [$test->id]);
}
```

Blade file:

```
function endQuiz(){
       // $('#explanation').empty();

       // console.log(score);
        $('#question').empty();
        $('#choice-block').empty();
        $('#submitbutton').remove();
         $(document.createElement('h2')).css({'text-align':'center', 'font-size':'4em'}).text('Congratulation!! You have successfully completed your test.').insertAfter('#question');

        var jsonString =JSON.stringify(score);
        /*alert(jsonString);*/
         $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/scores",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data:{'jsonString':jsonString},
        success: function(data){
               alert("Test Completed")
             // window.location.href = "{{('/home')}}";
        },
        error: function(data){
             alert("Test Completed")
             // window.location.href = "{{('/home')}}";
        }
    });
    }
```

Please help me out with the problem.

Comment: Are you getting a 500 Internal Server Error ? If so
Try changing the "url" in the AJAX request, by mentioning it in the below way. I have used it this way and it works for me
url: '{{ URL::action ('<YourControllerFileName>@store') }}'
It has not recognized the plain URL for me too.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. but it is not working. Can u help me out with some code snippet? for clear understanding.

Comment: what is the error you get ? Is it a 500 Internal Server Error ? Also you need to return a json response from your controller

Comment: Yes i got a 500 Internal server error.. what i need to do is send my data from tha ajax(which i have written inside the blade file)  to my controller..  so.that i can send the data to my DB

Comment: try Something like this 
In the Blade file, you need to have something like this

function endQuiz() {     
// Do your stuff here

// Make an AJAX request     $.ajax({         type: 'post',         url: '{{ URL::action (‘SomeController@store’) }}',         data: json_encode(score);         success: function(result) {         if(result.success) {             console.log("Success");         }         },         error: function() {             console.log(error);         }     }); }


In the Controller, you should return a json response

return response(array('success' => true));

Answer (score 0):

In the Blade file, you need to have something like this

```
function endQuiz() {
// Do your stuff here
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(score);

// Make an AJAX request         
$.ajax({             
type: 'post',             
url: '{{ URL::action (‘SomeController@store’) }}',             
data: jsonString,       
success: function(result) {             
   if(result.success) {                 
      console.log("Success");             
   }             
},             
error: function() {                 
   console.log(error);             
   }         
});     
}
```

In the Controller, you should return a json response, which can be a combination of arrays. Example like this

```
return response(array('success' => true));
```

Comment: No sir i am facing the same problem with this one as well. Internal Error 500

Comment: Can you check if the ajax call reaches the store function ? Put a **dd($request->all()) statement in your store function for debugging purpose. Then make the Ajax call in your web page and check The network tab (in xHR) on chrome  to see if the dd statement prints anything. You can know if it reaches store function or not

Comment: Yes sir it worked for me.. the problem was in the controller.. the value i was passing needs to passed within the explode function of removal of , [ ] . Thats y it was showing an internal error.. pass ing the json within the explode functions helped in my case..